# Opening the flag dialog on a comment too quickly shows the wrong error

Tags: bug, comment-flags

When attempting to flag multiple comments too quickly, I noticed the error dialog that appears shows an incorrect error message:

[image: Flag Dialog]

I didn't vote to flag the same comment twice, I voted to flag a different comment.  If it matters, the comments were both by the same user.

The error message should be changed to reflect that I can't flag *any* comment until 3 seconds have passed.